# How can I solve this problem with boolean?

Tags: objects

I'm trying to make a simple robot hand using tension. But when I try to create a hole in the smallest piece(handpart1) with the long cylinder(hole making), the smallest piece disappears. Is there a way to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 0):

Apply the scale of all your objects (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>), use the *Fast* option of the *Boolean* modifier instead of *Exact*, move the *hole making* object slightly on Z so that edges don't overlap, and it seems to work:

[image]